# Azure IoT Push notifications

Tags: javascript, azure, push-notification, iot, azure-iot-hub

I'm little confused by using Azure IoT Hub. I can't figure out how is it possible to trigger api function of sending push notifications for iOS/Android stored on Azure by IoT device using IoT Hub?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Azure IoT Hub has an Event Hub endpoint which you can connect to process device messages. Once you receive a message you can utilize Azure Notification Hub to send notifications to android/iOS.

Here's a [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-process-d2c/) to a tutorial on processing device to cloud messages.

Comment: Thank you for response! Is there any tutorial of how to connect IoT Hub with Event Hub?

Comment: @DmitriyStupivtsev checkout the link in the answer now for a tutorial on processing messages from a device.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and check your answer as solution if it will be helpful.

Comment: steps for route data of IoT-Hub to Event hub, 
1: login to your azure portal.  <br/>
2: configure IOT-HUB.  
3: configure Event-HUB <br/>
4: select own configured IOT-HUB and create devcie <br/>
5: select End Point. <br/>
6: Add new End point and while creating end point, please select Event-Hub. <br/>
7: select Routes option into IOT-HUB <br/>
8: create route fallowed by data source and end point.  <br/>

Now you have to subscript event-hub and now you are able to  ingest data of IOT-HUB